# Cloud Foundry multi-node environment RestClient Request Timeout during VMC push

Tags: ruby, sinatra, vmware, cloud-foundry

I am using VMC 0.3.18 and I set up my environment like the one discussed here: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20407923-single-multi-node-vcap-deployment-using-dev-setup

Each VM VCAP status claims their services are running (i.e. vcap_dev status) but when ever I try to push an application that I know works (successfully tested it in a single-node environment), I receive a HTTP exception: RestClient Timeout. Here is what the line looks out when the application is pushed.

```
root@myHome:~/Ruby/Hello# vmc push hello
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: Y
Detected a Sinatra Application, is this correct? [Yn]: Y
Application Deployed URL [hello.vcap.me]: hello.vcap.me
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [128M]: 128M
How many instances? [1]: 1
Bind existing services to 'hello'? [yN]: N
Create services to bind to 'hello'? [yN]: N
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: N
Creating Application: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (0K): OK
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'hello': .............................................HTTP exception: RestClient::RequestTimeout:Request Timeout
```

These application I have been attempting to load are simple hello.rb file http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/installing-vmc.html#next-steps (scroll up to see the file) and env.rb, to echo the page's environment variable  (on the bottom of the single-node\multi-node page mentioned above)

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the log files tell you?

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the log files to assist. Do you have any particular I should reinvestigate. I have went through the logs in the cloudfoundry/.deployments/rest/log for anything to state why the error keeps coming up.

Comment: I could send you zip copy of the log files if that would assist in the diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that you have used for your multi-node setup is very old and cloud foundry is on a rapid development phase.

Here is where you will find active conversations on vcap:
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev

If you are thinking of using chef for your multi-node cf installation, would recommend you to use Andrea Campi's scripts here: https://github.com/zephirworks - note that this is an independent project. The Cloud Foundry team is moving away from dev_setup and towards both BOSH installs.